# definite integral of a periodic function over the whole period

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve an integral. I was able to simplify it to the following form but I'm stuck now:
$$
\int\limits_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{d}x \ \frac{a-b\cos(x)}{[2(c-\cos(x)) +d]^{3/2}}
$$
I know that I can remove the 2 in the denominator aswell as combine $c$ and $d$, but I'd rather keep them separated for my solution. Also I should be able to somehow exploit the fact that the integral is over the whole period of the function.

I think I don't see a neat substitution to reduce it to an integral of a polynomial or something. Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).  I'm unaware if it will work, but it's a good start.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(a+-cos(x))%2F(2(c-cos(x))+%2B+d)%5E(3%2F2)

Comment: @Mark. I am afraid that this would lead to some awful elliptic integrals. Looking at what arthur posted, I am quite afraid !

Comment: Are you sure that you need that for any value of $a,b,c,d$ ?

Comment: Well I have $a,b,d>0$ and $c\ge1$ but other than that I need it for all possible values. So I guess there is no useful analytical solution then.

Comment: @user44789 a solution in terms of elliptic integrals might be useful because they are well studied and have many known properties